# Messages on OS X stopped working after iOS 7.1 upgrade

Tags: macos, ios, messages

After upgrading my iPhone 5 to iOS 7.1 the Messages app on my OS X 10.9.2 installation can no longer send messages via iMessage to other iMessage users. Sending messages via other services such as Google Talk is working fine. I have tried signing in and out from my iCloud account in Messages. Also, nothing has changed on the firewall I'm connected through.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your computer. That solved it for me.

Comment: Restarting is a good idea whenever you install any system upgrade.

Comment: I think I didn't think about that option initially since the upgrade was on my phone, not my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Activity Monitor, find and quit the [apsd](http://www.macinside.info/process.php?name=apsd) process (Apple Push notification Service Daemon). The process will automatically restart itself, and this can fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! If I ever run into this issue again I'll give this a try. However, I haven't had the problem since I restarted my MacBook which would have effectively done that.